# SP analysis failed in gfortran compiled application

Tags: ida

I need assistance in ida pro regarding sp analysis failure.
The link to the dissembled function is here:
http://pastebin.com/XRwzswgS
The program has a lot of these errors which hinders hexrays decompilation.
The analysis failure is shown in line 333 in pastebin. I have included the SP pointer values from ida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a line 34 you have a following code:

```
.text:0046FC96 010                 mov     eax, 3AFCh
.text:0046FC9B 010                 call    __alloca
```

This code allocates `0x3afc` bytes on stack and this allocation is not reflected in IDA stack analysis (if the assumption that `_alloca` function detected and defined correctly is correct, see [linux alloca man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) and [MSDN alloca documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx) for more details about this function).

To fix this you should go to `call _alloca` instruction, press <kbd>ALt</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> and insert the needed value (probably `-0x3afc` in your specific case, but I'm not sure).

This will hint IDA that there is a stack pointer change here.

Comment: By the way, this specific problem may be solved automatically with IDAPython. ALT-K is alike IDAPython api function idaapi.add_user_stkpnt(ea, delta), all the rest is obvious.